# Event listener doesn't trigger dynamically created element on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem triggering dynamically created button. Event listener only works fine if element is created manually.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="create">Create new button</button>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById("create").addEventListener('click', (x) => {
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "<button id='show'>Show alert</button>";});

document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click', (b) => {
alert("It works");});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

//Sorted out with event delegation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="create">Create new button</button>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById("create").addEventListener('click', (x) => {
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "<button class='show'>Show alert</button>";
});
const parent = document.getElementById('mydiv');
parent.addEventListener('click', (b) => {
if (x.target.className === 'show') {alert("It works")}
;});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to try using event delegation instead?

Comment: I want to create one page website were would be many different containers which will refresh or disappears or appears triggered by event listener.

Comment: Thanks event delgation works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You must move the code that binds the new element into the event handler for the code that creates it because when the event binding for the new element is outside, it fails immediately because the element doesn't exist.

In other words, you have to wait for the element to exist before you can bind it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="create">Create new button</button>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById("create").addEventListener('click', (x) => {

  document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "<button id='show'>Show alert</button>";
  
  // This code won't be run until after the new element is created, so it will
  // be safe to reference it at that point.
  document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click', (b) => {
    alert("It works");
  });
  
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="create">Create new button</button>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("create").addEventListener('click', (x) => {
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "<button id='show'>Show alert</button>";});
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id== 'show'){
        alert("It works");
     }
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```